# Sorting an arraycollection on multiple properties using sortfield is not working as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

The following works as expected with the sort compare function, but doesn't if I set descending to true.

```
var dataSortField:SortField = new SortField("y", false, false, true);
var dataSortField2:SortField = new SortField("x", false, true, true);

dataSortField2.compareFunction = 
    function sort(item1:Object, item2:Object):int {
        return -1 * (ObjectUtil.numericCompare(item1.x, item2.x));
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't [work]"? Does a run/compile time error occur or do you receive unexpected output? The information you've provided only allows us to guess at what might fix your problem.

Comment: I mean the sorting is not happening on the x property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use **true** or **false** for **Ascending/Descending** because you have a custom `compareFunction`. Here is a basic example how you can use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
    import spark.collections.Sort;
    import spark.collections.SortField;

    private var arrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {x:5, Name:"Adam Lee"},
        {x:2, Name:"Bryan Hobb"},
        {x:3, Name:"Claudia Toledo"},
        {x:7, Name:"Matt Brill"},
        {x:8, Name:"Justin Hinz"},
        {x:4, Name:"Bikram Dangol"}
    ])

    private function onAscendingButtonClick():void
    {
        var dataSortField2:SortField = new SortField();
        dataSortField2.compareFunction = sortAscendingCompareFunction;
        arrayCollection.sort = new Sort();
        arrayCollection.sort.fields = [dataSortField2];
        arrayCollection.refresh();
    }

    private function sortAscendingCompareFunction(item1:Object, item2:Object):int
    {
        return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(item1.x, item2.x);
    }

    private function sortDesscendingCompareFunction(item1:Object, item2:Object):int
    {
        return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(item2.x, item1.x);
    }

    private function onDescendingButtonClick():void
    {
        var dataSortField2:SortField = new SortField();
        dataSortField2.compareFunction = sortDesscendingCompareFunction;
        arrayCollection.sort = new Sort();
        arrayCollection.sort.fields = [dataSortField2];
        arrayCollection.refresh();
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button label="Sort Ascending" click="{onAscendingButtonClick()}"/>
        <s:Button label="Sort Descending" click="{onDescendingButtonClick()}"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Panel title="Sort using compareFunction" width="100%" backgroundColor="green">
        <s:DataGrid dataProvider="{arrayCollection}" sortableColumns="false" width="100%"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

[image: Custom Sort]

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The point I'm trying to make is that, the sort compare function shouldn't be necessary. If I remove the sort compare function, the sort fields should still work based on the third parameter of the constructor, but they are not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use custom `compareFunction` then this is how you could achieve **ascending/descending** feature:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
    import spark.collections.Sort;
    import spark.collections.SortField;

    private var arrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {x:5, Name:"Adam Lee"},
        {x:2, Name:"Bryan Hobb"},
        {x:3, Name:"Claudia Toledo"},
        {x:7, Name:"Matt Brill"},
        {x:8, Name:"Justin Hinz"},
        {x:4, Name:"Bikram Dangol"}
    ])

    private function onAscendingButtonClick():void
    {
        var dataSortField2:SortField = new SortField("x", false, true);
        //dataSortField2.compareFunction = sortAscendingCompareFunction;
        arrayCollection.sort = new Sort();
        arrayCollection.sort.fields = [dataSortField2];
        arrayCollection.refresh();
    }

    private function sortAscendingCompareFunction(item1:Object, item2:Object):int
    {
        return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(item1.x, item2.x);
    }

    private function sortDesscendingCompareFunction(item1:Object, item2:Object):int
    {
        return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(item2.x, item1.x);
    }

    private function onDescendingButtonClick():void
    {
        var dataSortField2:SortField = new SortField("x", true, true);
        //dataSortField2.compareFunction = sortDesscendingCompareFunction;
        arrayCollection.sort = new Sort();
        arrayCollection.sort.fields = [dataSortField2];
        arrayCollection.refresh();
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button label="Sort Ascending" click="{onAscendingButtonClick()}"/>
        <s:Button label="Sort Descending" click="{onDescendingButtonClick()}"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Panel title="Sort without compareFunction" width="100%" backgroundColor="green">
        <s:DataGrid dataProvider="{arrayCollection}" sortableColumns="false" width="100%"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: If I just pass the first field, it works. What I'm trying to do is pass two sort fields, and set the first one to ascending, and the second one to descending. The first sort field works as expected, but the second sort field doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use multiple `SortField`. First sort by the first **Field** in **ascending** order. If they are same then sort by the second **Field** in **descending** order. If you use `compareFunction`, that gets precedence. In your case don't use `compareFunction` as you are using **descending** as `true` for `SortField` **x**.
Below is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import spark.collections.Sort;
    import spark.collections.SortField;

    private var arrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {x:3, Name:"Claudia Toledo"},
        {x:5, Name:"Adam Lee"},
        {x:7, Name:"Adam Lee"},
        {x:2, Name:"Bryan Hobb"},
        {x:7, Name:"Matt Brill"},
        {x:4, Name:"Bikram Dangol"},
        {x:4, Name:"Adam Lee"},
        {x:9, Name:"Bikram Dangol"},
        {x:8, Name:"Justin Hinz"},
        {x:2, Name:"Bikram Dangol"}
    ]);

    private function onSortButtonClick():void
    {
        var dataSortField1:SortField = new SortField("Name", false, false);
        var dataSortField2:SortField = new SortField("x", true, true);
        arrayCollection.sort = new Sort();
        arrayCollection.sort.fields = [dataSortField1,dataSortField2];
        arrayCollection.refresh();
    }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
        <s:Button label="Sort Ascending Name and Descending x" click="{onSortButtonClick()}"/>
    <s:Panel title="Multiple Field Sort" width="100%" backgroundColor="green">
        <s:DataGrid dataProvider="{arrayCollection}" sortableColumns="false" width="100%"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

[image: Multiple Sort Example]